Nodemailer Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 2404:6800:4003:c1c::6c:465
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  host: "smtp.gmail.com", // tried to use host from smtp
  port: 465, // tried suggestion to use 465 or 587 but the response error didn't change
  secure: true, // tried to use secure as suggestion
  family: 4, // IPv4 some tried to force it
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER, // Gmail address
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS, // App password
  },
});

I'm using Nodemailer to send emails through Gmail's SMTP server in a Node.js app, and it works fine on my local machine. However, when I deploy the app to my cPanel hosting its given me this response Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 2404:6800:4003:c1c::6c:465

I changed the port to 587 with secure: false for STARTTLS but the error persists.
I cleared the browser cache and redeployed the code.

Environtment
cPanel hosting (Shared Hosting)
Node.js application running on a production server
How can I resolve this ECONNREFUSED error on my production server? Is this an issue with the hosting provider blocking outbound SMTP connections, or is there something else I should check in my setup?
thankyou
